OSB logging - Delay between WAF and OSB middleware
My problem is that I have a delay in my service when trying to hit OSB
I don't know if the problem is from middleware or WAF(network)
To insure that the problem is not from middleware I need to know when the request hit the service
can you provide us with a solution

You could place a log or report in the pipeline flow and with this see the time it enters and the time it ends.
You could also test the components you use independently, for example business service.
